# JavaScript simple function(e)

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain me why the function doesn't work when there are no arguments in the parentheses? I mean exactly "button" and "e". It seems to me that since a function is written for every "btns" element, it should automatically refer to it.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.question-btn');

btns.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const question = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
        question.classList.toggle('show-text');
    })
});
```

Comment: *"...when there are no arguments in the parentheses?"* What do you mean by that?

Comment: The question seems to be "Why don't functions automatically infer their arguments from loose variables". How would that work and why would this be expected or beneficial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean you don't understand why you need `button` and `e` in the parameter lists and can't just have:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.question-btn');

btns.forEach(function(/*no `button` here*/){
    ???.addEventListener('click', function(/*no `e` here*/){
        const question = ???.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
        question.classList.toggle('show-text');
    })
});
```

...then answer is the `???` in the above. The `button` parameter¹ is how the `forEach` callback code can refer to the specific button being handled by that call to the `forEach` callback (the button that `forEach` passed as an argument¹ to the callback when calling it); without it, it doesn't have anything to work with. Similarly, the `e` parameter is how the event handler code can refer to the event it's handling (the event argument that the event system in the browser called the function with).

Here's what may be a simpler example of the button thing:

```js
function setUpHandler(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("Clicked!");
    });
}

const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
setUpHandler(btn1);
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
setUpHandler(btn2);
```

```html
<input type="button" class="question-btn" id="btn1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" class="question-btn" id="btn2" value="Button 2">
```

The two calls to `setUpButton` there are just like the two calls that `forEach` would make to it if we did this *(except that `forEach` would also pass further arguments [the index and the list] that `setUpHandler` just ignores because it doesn't declare parameters to receive them in)*:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".question-btn").forEach(setUpHandler);
```

The `button` in `setUpHandler` is the *parameter* that the function receives that first *argument* in.

---

¹ Just a quick note on the terms "parameter" and "argument" since they came up above:

```
function add(a, b) {
//           ^−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− "parameters"
    return a + b;
}
const sum = add(1, 2)
//              ^−−^−−−−−−−−−−−− "arguments"
console.log(sum);
```

A *parameter* is the named thing (like a variable) that a function uses to refers to the *argument* passed to it when it's called. In the above, the parameters are `a` and `b`. The arguments are the values `1` and `2`. (And we also pass `console.log` an argument: `sum`.)